# Constructor Regex in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

My code is as follows:

```
var regex = new RegExp ('(.*/*)');
console.log(regex);
```

I think the result is:

```
/(.*/*)/
```

But the actual result is:

```
/(.*\/*)/
```

Could someone please explain this for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you expect the last asterisk `*` to be literal you need to escape it, otherwise it's a quantifier in regex meaning "match between zero and unlimited times". It's also recommened to escape the forward slash `/`, even if it might work without doing so.

```
(.*\/\*)
```

If you want to match `any string /* any string` then use:

```
(.*\/\*.*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/aJ4eA4/1

Answer (score 1):

The leading and trailing forward slashes are just how JavaScript represents a regex in string form and as a literal. The mean the same thing:

```
var regex = new RegExp ('(.*/*)');
```

is the same as

```
var regex = /(.*\/*)/;
```

It is important to escape the middle `/` otherwise it would interpret it as the end of the literal.

Comment: Sorry, how to have output is /(.*/*)/ if i want to use constructor of RegExp

Comment: @ThiepLV that would be invalid. why do you want it that way?

Comment: Because i want to match a pattern is more any character then /* or any other string